# Webpy uploading files, Understanding where does "imagename" come from?

Tags: python, file-upload, web.py

Using the web.py framework I am uploading files to my server [with this solution](http://webpy.org/cookbook/storeupload/) and works fine. My problem is that I'm not really sure where does the attribute '**filename**' come from? And how it actually gets the name of the file. This is at first a dictionary, isn't it?
I also read some of the [api reference](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/api) of web.py but didn't find anything relevant.
Here is some part of my code:

```
class Upload(object):
    def GET(self):
        return render.upload_form()

    def POST(self):
        update_form = web.input(file={})
        file_dir = '/Users/admin/Developer/projects/pro/templates/img'

        if 'file' in update_form:
            file_name = update_form.file.filename

            f_out = open(file_dir + '/' + file_name, 'w')
            f_out.write(update_form.file.file.read())
            f_out.close()

        return self.GET()
```

please look at line:

```
file_name = update_form.file.filename  # <- What???
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload a file, you need to use the [`multipart/form-data`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) content type. In a html form you do this by setting the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute of the form. For file inputs the browser automatically adds the filename to the request. A raw request would look something like this:

```
POST /upload HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=someboundary

--someboundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"; filename="filename.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

content of the file ....

--someboundary--
```

`name` is the name of the form element, and `filename` the original filename.

`web.py` imports the file as FieldStorage if you us a dict as default value in your code (see: ["Hang ups" here](http://webpy.org/cookbook/fileupload)), so that you can then query these information later. If you don't use a default, the file content is simple stored as string.

Be aware that the filename is user input and can by anything, therefore it needs to be sanitized! Somebody could upload a file like `"../../../some_directory/some_important_file"` and like this overwrite or create files anywhere the server process has access rights to do so.